# When i create new project in Apache NetBeans IDE 15 with simple (Java with Ant) than it shows me an error

Tags: java, netbeans, project, netbeans-15

I install JDK-13 with NetBeans-15 but after installation during creating a project I faced a problem that it shows the following message   **Project Folder already exists and is not empty.**

When I am facing that particular issue then I don't switch the path folder and set it on C: drive and also create a new folder in that drive but the same message shows.

Comment: It is not related to your error, but using Java 13 is generally not recommended, because it is not supported since March 2020 (with the exception of the version distributed by Azul). Currently supported versions are Java 8 (until 2026~2030), Java 11 (until 2024~2026), Java 17 (until 2027~2029) (LTS), and Java 19 (until the release of Java 20, later this month).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel It's not just a matter of using a supported version of Java; you should also use a version of Java supported by your IDE. In this specific case _"[The Apache NetBeans 15 binary releases require JDK 11+, and officially support running on JDK 11 and JDK 17](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb15/)"_, so the OP would be wise to use either Java 11 or Java 17. Other versions of Java may or may not work, but none of them are supported.

Comment: @David Review [the answers to existing questions on this error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bnetbeans%5D+%22Project+Folder+already+exists+and+is+not+empty%22).